# Best way to orchestrate jobs within python

Tags: python-3.x, workflow, jobs, orchestration

I am trying to launch several runs within a python script.

Each run consist of cloning a `git` repo, create a `venv`, set it up and run a `main.py` function.

What is the best way to launch many jobs in parallel and make the main script wait that the intermediate jobs end before continuing the post processing?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of orchestration is completely outside python programming scope

You need a shell script to run in your terminal.

I suppose you're using Linux, then create `run.sh` script with

```bash
python3 -m venv [VENV_NAME]

source [VENV_NAME]/bin/activate

git clone [GIT_URL]

cd [GIT_REPO_NAME]

python3 main.py
```

Second question is where you want to run it ? On your laptop, then use the script above, on Cloud services with virtual machines cluster then it is another topic

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I am still confused. Since I want to run dynamically many "runs" within my main run, what is the best way to make sure that all the intermediate runs have been completed before continuing? I don't know if my question is clear